# Accessing SQL server on-Prem database views from remote server through Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, azure-data-factory

We need to copy the data from client's remote SQL server (on-prem) database to our Azure SQL server through Azure data factory.

So we can automate the data pull on regular basis.

Client tried to offer us that they can create a domain login for us to access their database views. I would like to know if that works to make a connection via Azure Data Factory pipelines and linked service connections.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a Linked Service in ADF that uses Windows Authentication. A Linked Service can be thought of as similar to a connection manager in SSIS.

> [BOL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-linked-services)

You may then need to work out security and networking access, but as it stands, conceptually, you can use ADF to access on-prem SQL Servers using Windows Authentication.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Once they give me the domain login i will do that. In regards security and networking access will that be taken care as part of the domain login they are going to give us ? or any other settings we need to be looking into. (I am new to all these sorry if i am asking basic questions)

Comment: The team that provides the login should also help with any configuration of firewalls, networking, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you'll need to have them install a Self-Hosted Integration Runtime for the Data Factory is going to access their on-prem server.  See eg: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/50845

But if it's *your* data factory and *their* SQL Server on-prem, that might be a hard sell.  Another option is for them to use their own resources (Data Factory, SSIS, BCP+AzCopy) to export the table an upload it to *your* blob storage account.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for reply. Yes it will be our ADF and their SQL on Prem. Client side team is not very supportive to do any additional work for us to access it. SO trying to get them to create a domain login or create linked server on their on-prem for us. Any solution for this is appriciated.